# Ruby - how to create a rake task to search through every line of your project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I'm not sure how to approach this - I'm trying to create a script that will read through every file in a given directory take any lines containing a certain string, let's say 'bla', and copy them to a new file, giving me a file just with lines containing the string I'm searching for.

I'm not even sure where to look at the documentation.. If someone could point me in the right direction or give me some sample code I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Is using Ruby a hard requirement? If yes why? Otherwise a tool like `grep` might be a better choice.

Comment: Hadn't even occurred to me to be honest but seems like the best option - many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to use ruby for this; you can simply use `grep`:

```
grep -hr "search-string" /path/to/directory/ > output_file
```

Where -h is the parameter to hide the filename, and -r searches the directory recursively. As from `man grep`:

> **-h, --no-filename**
>
> Suppress the prefixing of file names on output. This is the default
>   when there is only one file (or only standard input) to search.
>
> **-R, -r, --recursive**
>
> Recursively search subdirectories listed.

Comment: Definitely a better solution - ruby's all I know so I guess I try and force solutions into that even if there are better options out there! Will use Grep now, many thanks.